# Referencing object UUID key to products in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi guys I've created an object with UUID and I want to connect the UUID to the respective items, I figured out that there's needs to be a way to separate the UUID from the rest of the object and but my issue lies in how to connect the id in the idArray to the button.
TL;DR when I click the "+" button it needs to increase the quantity of the stock by + 1, and the items need to be connected to their own id. Somehow in some ways, the UUID needs to act as an argument for the "addToCart" function.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Products</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Looping through products object using product as key -->
    <tr v-for="product in products">
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
        <td><input class="button" value="+" type="button" v-on:click="addToCart(product)"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- <tr>
      <td>Jacket</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><input class="button" type="button" value="+"></td>
    </tr> -->
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>{Total: 0}</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    new Vue({
  created() {
    //Displaying the pushed id as an array
    this.counter()
  },
  computed: {
    total() {
      return Object.values(this.products).reduce(
        (accumulator, value) => accumulator + value.price * value.quantity,
        0
      )
    }
  },
  data: {
    idArray: [],
    products: {
      "dd3ce0a3-1d30-4e3e-bcec-7095590019d9": { name: 'Jacket', price: 200, quantity: 0 },
      "faf68d1f-8f3e-4668-891c-56118cc330f4": { name: 'Pants', price: 100, quantity: 0 },
      "dd2bb41e-7f0a-4cb8-884b-588f9457dd54": { name: 'Shoes', price: 100, quantity: 0 }
    },

  },
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    //This functions takes all the UUID key and push it to idArray[] above
    counter() {
      let n = Object.keys(this.products);
      // console.log(n.length);
      for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        console.log(n[i])
        this.idArray.push(n[i])
      }
    },
    addToCart(productId) {
      this.products[productId].quantity++
    },
  }
})
  </script>
  <!-- <script src="index.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
v-for="(product, key) in products"
```

and use the `key` in the `addProducts` call:

```js
add products(key)
```

Comment: Thank you! I read about that v-for could take in two parameters which of them would be the object keys, But I was very tired after all shotgun debugging, Good man!